# How can I batch rename filenames in sequential order using the `rename` utility?

Tags: bash, rename

Let's say I have `a.jpg`, `b.jpg` and `c.jpg` and I want to rename them like this: `001.jpg`, `002.jpg` and `003.jpg`. **How should I do this using `rename`?**

EDIT: `rename 's/.*/expr/' *.jpg` | I need to change `expr` with something that will add 001, 002, 003 for each file.

Comment: There are far many questions for _exactly the same_ problem.  Try searching this site.

Comment: @devnull I've searched. I didn't find a solution. Also, I don't understand a thing of `perlexpr`.

Comment: hmm.. how about http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+rename+sequential

Comment: @devnull: I have seen lots of bash scripts. I'm not interested in those.

Comment: There are multiple incompatible versions of `rename` available: which are you using? Presumably, the Perl script, since you mention Perl regular expressions.

Comment: You have tagged your question as bash, but you are not interested in bash scripts? I'm confused.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I'm using the Perl script.

Comment: Before chepner's edit you had the batch-file tag. Are you using Windows? or bash on 'nix?

Comment: @dbenham I'm not using Windows. I used `bash` to describe the environment and `batch`, `rename` is self-explanatory. The expression I need is for `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

How about bash for loop over the jpg files.

```
for i in *.jpg ;do mv $i $((++c)).jpg ;done
```

Comment: This doesn't rename as 001, 002, 003. It renames as 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop generating also the leading zeros:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do name=00$((++c)); mv $i ${name: -3}.jpg ; done
```

Comment: This doesn't rename the files in order. It renames them in a random order.